# C# Async CTP Install and working in a team

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, asynchronous

I have downloaded the C# Async CTP and I am about to install it. However, I noticed on the install wizard that it affects the C# 4 Client Profile Library.

I work in a team and if I install this on my machine and make any changes to a solution will it affect the rest of the team's solution file? We all work off the same solution using Source Control and I don't want to affect anyone else's work!

Any ideas?

Comment: The Async CTP installs new types and extension methods, instead of directly patching code. So you should be OK. Example: `TaskEx` instead of updating the `Task` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I don't believe it will affect solution files at all - or have any other negative impact so long as you don't actually use the new contextual keywords and types in projects which aren't meant to use them.

Of course, you should be safe anyway so long as you check which files have changed and how they've changed before you check them in.

As Tejs mentioned, the CTP adds a library rather than changing existing libraries. It *does* change the compiler itself as well though - so it's *just barely possible* that you may notice some change to behaviour unrelated to async... but I think that's unlikely.

Comment: That's the answer I was looking for! +1